# ggcoef_model error when two random intercepts

Tags: r, ggplot2, broom, ggally, glmmtmb

When trying to graph the conditional fixed effects of a `glmmTMB` model with two random intercepts in `GGally` I get the error:

> There was an error calling "tidy_fun()". Most likely, this is because the
> function supplied in "tidy_fun=" was misspelled, does not exist, is not
> compatible with your object, or was missing necessary arguments (e.g. "conf.level=" or "conf.int="). See error message below.
> Error: Error in "stop_vctrs()":
> ! Can't recycle "..1" (size 3) to match "..2" (size 2).`

I have tinkered with figuring out the issue and it seems to be related to the two random intercepts included in the model. I have also tried extracting the coefficient and standard error information separately through `broom.mixed::tidy` and then feeding the data frame into `GGally:ggcoef()` with no avail. Any suggestions?

```r
# Example with built-in randu data set
data(randu)
randu$A <- factor(rep(c(1,2), 200))
randu$B <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4), 100))

# Model
test <- glmmTMB(y ~ x + z + (0 +x|A) + (1|B), family="gaussian", data=randu)

# A few of my attempts at graphing--works fine when only one random effects term is in model
ggcoef_model(test)

ggcoef_model(test, tidy_fun = broom.mixed::tidy)

ggcoef_model(test, tidy_fun = broom.mixed::tidy, conf.int = T, intercept=F)

ggcoef_model(test, tidy_fun = broom.mixed::tidy(test, effects="fixed", component = "cond", conf.int = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some (old!) bugs that have recently been fixed ([here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/pull/824), [here](https://github.com/bbolker/broom.mixed/commit/41d4e235b78ca6886328de49e33ee4ed7a11565c)) that would make confidence interval reporting on RE parameters break for *any* model with multiple random terms (I think). I believe that if you are able to install updated versions of *both* `glmmTMB` and `broom.mixed`:

```r
remotes::install_github("glmmTMB/glmmTMB/glmmTMB@ci_tweaks")
remotes::install_github("bbolker/broom.mixed")
```

then `ggcoef_model(test)` will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben, that works. However, I am still getting the same error when I try and plot a model with a large fixed theta for the conditional term. Any suggestions? Model example:

```test <- glmmTMB(y ~ x + z + (0 +x|A) + (1|B), family="gaussian", data=randu, start = list(theta = c(0,log(1e3))), map = list(theta = factor(c(1,NA))))```

Comment: Another buglet. I'll work on it.

Comment: OK, I think this should work OK with mapped parameters now, as long as you stick to Wald intervals and don't try with uniroot/profile intervals ...